# Invalid function while using aliasing in MySQl

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL I want to convert contents of one column to `UPPERCASE`.

The below statement works

```
select customer_id, upper(email) email from table
```

The below statement doesn't work

```
select c.customer_id, c.upper(email) email from table c
```

Why is this happening? what is the correct way to use functions while aliasing?

Comment: "Doesn't work" usually comes with an error message. ...but you're problem is that you need to "upper" `c.email`; "upper" is not a part of `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`UPPER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper) function isn't a function of the `table c`. You need to remove the `c.` in front of `c.UPPER(email)`. You can set the table prefix on the column name instead (`UPPER(c.email)`):

```
SELECT c.customer_id, UPPER(c.email) AS email FROM table_name c
```